# Как связать одну таблицу с другой в mysql через 2 разных поля

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

Чтобы объяснить, у меня есть таблица Компаний, в которой хранятся идентификаторы стран компаний и идентификаторы стран клиентов, которые относятся к одной и той же таблице Страны.
с такими колонками

первая таблица (companies)

```
id_el - id элемента
c_id - id страны компании
c_id_gen - id страны клиента
```

вторая таблица (countries)

```
c_id - id страны
c_name - Название страны
```

система использует конструктор запросов
создаю запрос

```
$this->db->join('countries', 'companies.c_id = countries.c_id', 'left');//таблицы по значениям id страны компании
$companiesArr = $this->db->get_where('companies')->result_array();//получаю массив
```

в итоге получаю массив стоящий из компаний со странами

```
array(
    [0]=>array{
        id_el  => 1
        c_id   => 15
        c_id_gen   => 12
        c_name   => Россия
    }
    [1]=>array{
        id_el  => 2
        c_id   => 10
        c_id_gen   => 13
        c_name   => Руанда
    }
    .....
)
```

но как объединить таблицы по id компании и по id страны клиента??

чтобы получилось что то вроде этого:

```
array(
    [0]=>array{
        id_el  => 1
        c_id   => 15
        c_id_gen   => 12
        c_name   => Россия
        c.c_name   => Болгария
    }
    [1]=>array{
        id_el  => 2
        c_id   => 10
        c_id_gen   => 13
        c_name   => Руанда
        c.c_name   => Казахстан
    }
    .....
)
```

пробовал вот так:

```
$this->db->join('countries', 'companies.c_id = countries.c_id', 'left');//таблицы по значениям id страны компании
$this->db->join('countries', 'companies.c_id_gen = countries.c_id', 'left');//таблицы по значениям id страны клиента
$companiesArr = $this->db->get_where('companies')->result_array();//получаю массив
```

но выходит ошибка

> Not unique table/alias: 'countries'

еще попробовал вот так:

```
$this->db->join('countries', 'companies.c_id = countries.c_id', 'left');//таблицы по значениям id страны компании
$this->db->join('countries AS generator', 'monitoring_companies.c_id = countries.c_id', 'left');// название страны клиента
```

но название страны компании затирается названием страны клиента

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->join('countries', 'companies.c_id = countries.c_id', 'left');//таблицы по значениям id страны компании
$this->db->join('countries', 'companies.c_id_gen = countries.c_id', 'left');//таблицы по значениям id страны производства
$companiesArr = $this->db->get_where('companies')->result_array();//получаю массив
```

А почему тут 2 `JOIN?` Вы так не можете делать. Так работать не будет. Судя по вопросу вам достаточно и (т.е. удалить первую строчку):

```
$this->db->join('countries', 'companies.c_id_gen = countries.c_id', 'left');//таблицы по значениям id страны производства
$companiesArr = $this->db->get_where('companies')->result_array();//получаю массив
```

---

`как получить название страны по столбцу c_id компании?`:

$C_ID - ваше значение.

```
$this->db->select('c_id_gen')->from('companies')->where('c_id', $C_ID);
$subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$RESULT = $this->db->select('c_name')
         ->from('countries')
         ->where("c_id IN ($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE)
         ->get()
         ->result();
```

Comment: как получить название страны по столбцу c_id  компании?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов добавил в ответ, как-то так. `->where("с_id IN ($subQuery)"` возможно стоит изменить на `->where("с_id = ($subQuery)"`.

Comment: ок, но как все таки связать таблицы попо c_id и по c_id_gen? 
чтобы в итоге получился массив похожи на тот что я привел как пример в вопросе.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов яж уже оветил вам, должен быть только один JOIN: `$this->db->join('countries', 'companies.c_id_gen = countries.c_id', 'left');`

Comment: в вашем ответе вы соединили таблицы только по c_id_gen соответвенно и страны в массиве на выходе будут храниться только по c_id_gen а мне нужно чтобы в массив записывались страны компаний и страны произодств которые ественно храняться в одной таблице.

Чтобы объяснить, у меня есть таблица Компаний, в которой хранятся идентификаторы стран адресов компаний и идентификаторы стран производств, которые относятся к одной и той же таблице Страны.